# is there a reason this script doesn't work in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a script for some navigation thing I have made... **Works perfectly in firefox but doesn't work after the fadeInUpBig part of the function.  I am wondering why this might be the case?**  I have also posted the css and html of the two classes that aren't loading in the script to help.

```
$('.fa-question-circle').parent().on('click', function () {
      $('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(0, 0);
      $("#colorscreen").remove();
      $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
      $("body").append('<div id="colorscreen" class="animated"></div>');
      $("#colorscreen").addClass("fadeInUpBig");
      $('.fadeInUpBig').css('background-color', 'rgba(33,29,134, 0.2)');
      $(".tile-area-main").css({width: "720px"}).load("what.html #overview");
      $(".submenu-ctn").load("what.html .submenu-what");
      $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');  
      $('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(3000, 1);
});
```

CSS for tile area main....

```
.metro .tile-area-main {
  position: fixed;
  left: 290px;
  top: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  width: auto;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index : 349;
  width: 720px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index : 3000;

}
.metro .tile-area-main p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 2.4em 0.6em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color : #fff;
    cursor: pointer;

}
```

and the html which is simple really...

```
<body class="metro">
<div class="tile-area-main"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? do you get a js error? does the screen go blank?

Comment: lol hahaha and sorry i wasn't more specific ... it performs the fadeinup big , (little animation with webkit ) but loading content into the container "tile-area-main" 9just a div with content in another html page ) this bit doesn't work it doesn't display aything at all... whereas in firefox it works fine ?? well wierd

Comment: ... screen doesn't go blank just no content displayed

Comment: btw, you should really learn what 'chaining' in jQuery does.

Comment: thanks for the tip , any ideas on why chrome and i.e are ignoring the content load ?

Comment: I am guessing by the immediate silence that this is really a css dependency issue embedded somewhere in my code where something as stupid as position:fixed will ruin my entire website ... just a hunch

Comment: why dont you answer the questions? is there something in the consle?? if the content is loaded, you should see it when you inspect the element, cant be a CSS thing i think..

Comment: nothing in console are there any other tools out there that compare browser rendering ?

Comment: sidenote - try to avoid setting css directly on element.For example, you could have easily done - $("body").append('<div id="colorscreen" class="animated fadeInUpBig someClass"></div>'); where someClass sets the background-color.

Comment: thanks for the tip I will take your advice .... does this potentially cause problems in chrome and i.e ?

Comment: Can you share a plunkr. That will make it easier for us to troubleshoot.

Comment: No, it's just a best practice. You don't need that many lines of code for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stupid post and stupid answer but there ya go... basically I was using a testing platform that was not configured properly... in the end i managed to get the browsers on my machine and test them ... worked find...... (oops)

Answer (score 0):

no errors in console? its hard to say then.. maybe like so?

```
$('.fa-question-circle').parent().on('click', function () {
      var submenuInCache = $('.submenu-ctn');
      //Cache objects if you use them often ... 

      submenuInCache.fadeTo(0, 0);
      $("#colorscreen").remove();
      $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
      $("body").append('<div id="colorscreen" class="animated"></div>');
      //$("#colorscreen").addClass("fadeInUpBig"); as connexo said, no sens to this here... 
      $('.fadeInUpBig').css('background-color', 'rgba(33,29,134, 0.2)');
      $(".tile-area-main").css({width: "720px"});
      $(".tile-area-main").load("what.html #overview");
      submenuInCache.load("what.html .submenu-what");
      $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');  
      submenuInCache.fadeTo(3000, 1);
});
```

Comment: it has to be the crappest question i have ever asked as it really doesn't help anyone explain exactly were the problem is , ... which is the problem i guess... i knew i was gonna get voted down ... going to start disasembling th site and see what the deal is maybe

Answer (score 0):

By "doesn't work" I assume you mean "doesn't behave as expected"?

One thing to point out that you may have missed is that jQuery fade events are asynchronous. The thread will not wait for them to complete so

```
$('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(0, 0);
$("#colorscreen").remove();
```

effectively results in `#colorscreen` being immediately removed. You should use callbacks for all this types of asynchronous effects:

```
$('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(0, 0, function() {
    $("#colorscreen").remove();
    ...
}
```